# Angular Karma testing objects: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ngxs

I have been stuck on this issue, which I do not now how to resolve or find a solution for.

I have an angular service which I use to get a day entry from a shopping list from my NGXS store.

However, it throws an error in the **ng test** saying *"Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined"*

The code in the service looks like this, fairly simple.

```
getDataFromStore(daySelected: string): DailyShopList {
    return this.store.selectSnapshot<DailyShopList>(
        state => state.shoppingList.dailyEntries[daySelected] <--- issue is here
    );
}
```

If you look at the line **state => state.shoppingList.dailyEntries[daySelected]**, 
this is where I get the error. 
When I remove the **[daySelected]** from the end of the object, I get no errors.

So, in my test file, I tried to mock the data as it would come from the store. But it still throws the error.

```
describe('ShoppingListService', () => {
    let service: ShoppingListService;
    const data = {
        state: {
            shoppingList: {
                dailyEntries: {
                    mon: {},
                    tue: {},
                },
            },
        },
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                NgxsModule.forRoot([MyNGXSstate]),
            ],
        });
        service = TestBed.inject(ShoppingListService);
        const store: Store = TestBed.get(Store);

        spyOn(store, 'selectSnapshot').and.returnValue(data); // trying to mock data from store
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: i got the same error :(